# Gitbucket forgotten password

Tags: linux, ubuntu

ihave a problem. i frogotten my password for my gitbucket repo. i have my gitbucket runnig on a VSP. Is there any good ways to reset, change or just get access to db and replace it? i have to do this from command line.
_

Comment: So this is a personal GitBucket repo? Did the VSP set it up for you, or did you set it up yourself?

Comment: https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/issues/872

Comment: i have made the install by myself

Comment: Can you use the [Reset password page](https://bitbucket.org/account/password/reset/)?

Comment: its not Bitbucket it's gitbucket :-)

Comment: Ok, then the link above should contain the instructions for doing this. You need to connect to the local db and modify it directly to change the pwd.